# jQuery Mobile: Same page with different data-urls

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a web application made with jQuery Mobile beta 2. The start page of the application has the URL http://server/mob/start.php and its page div has ID 'frontpage' and data-url is also 'frontpage'.

When I click a link from the start page and from the just opened page click Home button which points back to URL /mob/start.php, I end up with two frontpage divs in my DOM. The newly added frontpage has the same ID but its data-url is '/mob/start.php/'.

I could of course remove the page divs where I'm navigating away from but after the above described navigation the browser is pointed at URL /mob/start.php#/mob/start.php. Thus when I reload the page, I end up with same situation again.

What am I doing wrong because this problem doesn't seem to appear in jQueryMobile.com site?

**UPDATE**: Each page is an independent page and contains only one page div so links are not made by ID but by local relative URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated jQuery Mobile to beta 3 and can no longer reproduce the problem.